# Search XML and display in HTML

Tags: xml

What I'm trying to do is to make XML data searchable on an HTML page via the WorkOrderNum field to display the results of that customer in a table for that particular order. I'd also like to be able to bold the order number and highlight the fields/cells SchedLoadDate and SchedDelDate in a particular color. I've tried several suggestions on the site with no luck. I can get the whole XML file to display but nothing else. Any suggestions?

Sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mrmover>
    <customer>
        <WorkOrderNum>1000</WorkOrderNum>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <OriginCity>Sullivan</OriginCity>
        <OriginState>MO</OriginState>
        <OriginZip>63080</OriginZip>
        <DestinationCity>Chicago</DestinationCity>
        <DestinationState>IL</DestinationState>
        <DestinationZip>60423</DestinationZip>
        <SchedLoadDate>9/11/15</SchedLoadDate>
        <SchedDelDate>10/18/15</SchedDelDate>
    </customer>     
</mrmover>
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you have tried, and why it won't work?

Comment: Are you looking for [XML databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database)?

Comment: What I have now is an SQL database exporting to an XML file containing certain fields to a website. I want someone to be able to search in an html page via Order Number to list all those fields in a table for that order. I have tried the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016359/search-xml-with-javascript-and-display-results-in-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118057/search-an-xml-file-and-display-results-with-javascript?lq=1